# ErrorException Undefined variable:

Tags: php, laravel, e-commerce

Why I am getting this error?
ErrorException
Undefined variable: features (View: C:\xampp\htdocs....views\layouts\index.blade.php)

**FeaturedController.php**

```
 public function index()
             {
                $features = Feature::get();
                return view ('layouts.index')->with(compact('features'));
        
            }
```

**ProductsController.php**

```
public function index()
    {
        $products = Product::get();
        return view ('products')->with(compact('products'));
      
    }
```

**layouts page- index.blade.php**

```
 @yield('content')
     @foreach($features as $f)
         <li>
              <div class="prodcut-price mt-auto">
                  <div class="font-size-15">LKR {{ $f ['features_id'] }}.00</div>
             </div>
         </li>
        @endforeach
```

**view page - index.blade.php**

```
@extends('layouts.index')
@section('content')

  @foreach($products as $p)
                       <div class="mb-2"><a href="../shop/product-categories-7-column-full-width.html" class="font-size-12 atext">{{ $p ['prod_sub_category'] }}</a></div>
                                            <h5 class="mb-1 product-item__title"><a href="../shop/single-product-fullwidth.html" class="text-blue font-weight-bold">{{ $p ['prod_name'] }}</a></h5>
                                            <div class="mb-2">
                                                <a href="../shop/single-product-fullwidth.html" class="d-block text-center"><img class="img-fluid" src="{{asset('/storage/admin/'.$p ['prod_image_path'] ) }}"  alt="Image Description"></a>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="flex-center-between mb-1">
                                                <div class="prodcut-price">
                                                    <div class="atext">LKR {{ $p ['prod_price'] }}.00</div>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="d-none d-xl-block prodcut-add-cart">
                                                    <a href="../shop/single-product-fullwidth.html" class="btn-add-cart btn-primary transition-3d-hover"><i class="ec ec-shopping-bag"></i></a>
                                                </div>
```

**web.php**

```
Route::resource('/products', 'ProductsController');

Route::resource('/layouts/index', 'FeaturedController@index');
```

Comment: dont need with just return view ('layouts.index', compact('features'));

Comment: @AlzafanChristian Even though I change it throws the same error.

Comment: can you edit, with full html because i saw @yield there, supposed to be a @extends()

Comment: if im right, the error comes when u accessed ProductsController@index then you should pass Features::get() into compact('products', 'features'); because $features not passed to parent view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as u r using data in `layout` u should use laravel view composer to share data to layout file  ref link https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/views#view-composers

in your `AppServiceProvider.php`

inside `boot()` add this line

```php
 public function boot()
    {
       \View::composer('layouts.index', function ($view) { // here layout path u need to add
        $features = Feature::get();
         $view->with([
            'features'=>$features,
         ]);
});
}
```

> It share data based on specif view file like here `layouts.index` data is send to this view so if u not send data from controller it will get data from `view composer`

Comment: Actually what is happening with this view composer? Can you please explain?

Comment: it share data based on specif view file like here `layouts.index` data is send to this view so if u not send data from controller it will get data from `view composer`

Comment: I am self-studying Laravel with the help of Laraevl document. Can you please suggest me any other resources to study Laravel. @Kamlesh Paul

Comment: @Zeenath i also self learned all  and for learning laravel doc and https://laracasts.com/ this is best and please marke this answer if it solved your problem

Answer (score 2):

Aside from not passing your variables to your blade views appropriately which other answers have pointed out, your trying to access `features` from a controller that does not have features set.

The controller below sets features and then makes use of it in the `layouts.index` blade file.

FeaturedController.php

```
public function index()
{
    $features = Feature::get();

    return view ('layouts.index')->with(['features' => $features]);

    // or

    // return view ('layouts.index', compact('features'));
        
}
```

While this controller sets `products` but then makes use of a blade file that extends another blade file that has a `features` variable in it. This is why your getting the error

ProductsController.php

```
public function index()
{
    $products = Product::get();

    return view ('products', compact('products'));
}
```

And to fix it you must pass the `features` variable along side `products` like so:

ProductsController.php

```
public function index()
{
    $products = Product::get();
    $features = Feature::get();

    return view ('products')->with(['features' => $features, 'products' => $products]);
}
```

But if more than one blade file is going to extend this `layouts.index` file then this approach is not advisable, and situations like this is why Taylor Otwell introduced [Blade Components](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/blade#components). You can now move the `features` blade view and logic to a component that can wrap around any other file you want or be included.

The documentation is straight forward but if you want me to show you how to implement it to solve your dilemma then hit me up on the comment below.

Comment: i suggested View::composer() instead

Comment: Personally i think the new component feature in laravel 7 that allows you to include it with the `<x></x>`  prefix is more flexible. but if he is not using laravel 7 then I guess view composer will do.

Comment: i know, but he need to know the basic, and as if he used 7.x, just my opinion xD

Comment: Well, just because we are old heads don't mean the new kids have to learn techniques that are arguably out of date, cos it may still be in the Laravel framework, but on the low its just a few releases away from being flagged `deprecated`. Just my opinion.

Comment: nvm, i would suggest for now is using View::composer, then if he use 7.x version he can use the new component feature in the answer, in 7.x view composer still there and easier to manage without using extra blade. just suggestion to improving your answer.

Comment: @tsommie I am using laravel 7.21.0 <x></x> What is meant by this? Can you please guide me to sort out this?

Comment: @tsommie                                                                                         
ArgumentCountError
Too few arguments to function Illuminate\Routing\PendingResourceRegistration::name(), 1 passed in C:\..routes\web.php on line 39 and exactly 2 expected I got this error when i change the code as above

Comment: Go to your routes file on line 39, your probably passing one argument instead of two. it has nothing to do with the code above.

Answer (score 1):

You can change your controller to this:

```
 public function index()
 {
     $features = Feature::all();
     return view ('layouts.index', compact('features'));
        
  }
```

A your blade you should actually do @section instead:

```
@section('content')
    @foreach($features as $f)
         <li>
              <div class="prodcut-price mt-auto">
                  <div class="font-size-15">LKR {{ $f->features_id }}.00</div>
             </div>
         </li>
     @endforeach
@endsection
```

Comment: i asked for a full html, i saw the same xD